# How do you make a child label smaller than its parent frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

There is only one frame in my GUI, and it resizes itself to the size of the window. The frame has a child label, and I want the label to always be 1/3 the height of the frame and 1/1.5 the width of the frame. The code below tries to do that but the label always resizes itself to the size of the frame.

```
import tkinter

tk = tkinter.Tk()
tk.geometry("400x400")
f = tkinter.Frame(tk, bd=5, bg="white")
f.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

def callback(event):
    f.config(height=tk.winfo_height(), width=tk.winfo_width())
    l.config(width=int(f.winfo_width()/1.5), height=int(f.winfo_height()/3))
    
l = tkinter.Label(f, text="lead me lord", bg="yellow", relief=tkinter.RAISED, bd=5)
l.pack(side="bottom")

tk.bind("<Configure>", callback)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this label the only thing in the frame, and the frame the only thing in the window? Often, the way to layout a single label will be different if it's the only widget versus when there are many other widgets.  We can tell you how to achieve what you want, but if you plan on adding other widgets then it could just create other problems unless we know the overall plan for the window.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height of the label are in characters.  In order to use pixels, you need to add an empty image to the label:

```
img = tkinter.PhotoImage() # an image of size 0
l = tkinter.Label(f, text="lead me lord", bg="yellow", relief=tkinter.RAISED, bd=5,
                  image=img, compound='center')
```

---

Actually you don't need to resize the frame in the callback if you add `fill="both", expand=1` into `f.pack(...)`:

```
import tkinter

tk = tkinter.Tk()
tk.geometry("400x400")

f = tkinter.Frame(tk, bd=5, bg="white")
f.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=1)

def callback(event):
    l.config(width=int(f.winfo_width()/1.5), height=int(f.winfo_height()/3))
    #l.config(width=event.width*2//3, height=event.height//3)  # same as above line if bind on frame

img = tkinter.PhotoImage()
l = tkinter.Label(f, text="lead me lord", bg="yellow", relief=tkinter.RAISED, bd=5,
                  image=img, compound='center')
l.pack(side="bottom")

f.bind("<Configure>", callback) # bind on frame instead of root window
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your precise specifications, the best solution is to use `place` since it lets you use relative widths and heights. However, if you plan to have other widgets in the window, `place` is rarely the right choice.

This example will do exactly what you asked: place the label at the bottom with 1/3 the height and 1/1.5 the width. There is no need to have a callback for when the window changes size.

Note: I had to change the call to `pack` for the frame. The text of your question said it would expand to fill the window but the code you had wasn't doing that. I added the `fill` and `expand` options.

```
import tkinter

tk = tkinter.Tk()
tk.geometry("400x400")
f = tkinter.Frame(tk, bd=5, bg="white")
f.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=True)

l = tkinter.Label(f, text="lead me lord", bg="yellow", relief=tkinter.RAISED, bd=5)
l.place(relx=.5, rely=1.0, anchor="s", relheight=1/3., relwidth=1/1.5)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of window]